# Selecting different languages from SQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, session, multilingual

I'm having a 2 issues with my website.
It's a multi language one (german, english). 
I always kept the translations in an XML document like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <les>
        <en>Lesson</en>
        <de>Lektion</de>
    </les>
```

Then I converted those XML vars into php ones and echo'd them where needed like this

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("langindex.xml") or die("xml not found!");
$les = $xml->les->$lang;

<?php echo $les;?>
```

Problem 1 is that no language is set as default when I open the Website so I always have to select a language first, even though I included that !isset. If I don't select anything, some images will be streched and it gives me the error that no language is set.

```
<?php
session_start();
$page = 0;
$lang = $_GET['lang'];
$langArray = array('en','de');
$found = false;

if(in_array($lang, $langArray))
    $found = true;
if(!$found)
    $lang = 'en';

if(!isset($_SESSION['lang']))
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';

if(isset($_GET['lang']) && in_array($_GET['lang'], array('en', 'de')))
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];


include '../nihongo/php/dbconnect.php';
```

My language switch works with a simple `<a href="?lang=X">` and that ?lang=X will be shown in the URL as well.

Enough of that. 
Since XML is pretty inpractical I wanted to switch the whole thing up to an SQL database.

I've created a table with the columns ID, german and english and connected the db sucessfully.
Now I want PHP to tell SQL to get only the text of the session language with a select like this for example.

```
SELECT german FROM texts WHERE ID = '1'
SELECT english FROM texts WHERE ID = '2'
```

My problem is that I really don't know how to do that with PHP.
I would think that I'd either have to throw a PHP var into the statement somehow, or select the whole row and let PHP decide which one should be displayed.
Every advice/suggestion is welcome!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it depends on how you want to attack this.  You could make a function that queries for a key and then have it output the text for example if you had some html like this: <a href='....'><?= getText('main_menu', 'german') ?></a>  Also, if I was going to use a database, I probably would have redis, or memcache being checked first before the database.  To tell you the truth I would probably use gettext and only use the database as a way to generate those files after the translation company used a tool to populate, and use a TAL template.

Comment: Instead of trying to develop a custom implementation of i18n, I would use an existing library that is well maintained and proven to work like https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation.html or https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-i18n/.

Answer (score 0):

I like the way OpenCart implemented this, because it's simple and doesn't add additional calls to the DB. Take a look at their implementation. You learn a lot investigating and learning from Open Source projects.

They have a php script per language and module with an array that contains all the strings. It just include or load the scripts to get access to the strings, for example: [en-gb](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/catalog/language/en-gb/en-gb.php). Loading a string by its key with this method:

```
language->get('heading_title');
```